# How to read input from text on button click unobtrusively in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

How to read input from text on button click unobtrusively in Javascript? Can anyone provide a sample?

```
<script type="text/javascript>
window.onload = function() {

var btn = document.getElementById(
    "btn"
);
btn.addEventListener("click",function() { alert("bar"); },false);

}
</script>
```

and in the body:

```
<div id="content">
<input type="text" id="percent" value="" />
<button id="btn">click</button></div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  It's hard to know exactly what you're asking, try reading http://stackoverflow.com/ask-advice and see how you can improve your question.

Comment: Some HTML markup of what you're trying to do might help in understanding what you're asking for.

Comment: Did you mean something like this ? (simplified example) : http://jsfiddle.net/ACwJM/

Comment: Cronos, +1 just make it an answer.

Comment: thanks, i was not able to add code properly, thats another so question :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, addEventListener (with IE's attachEvent) is the most unobtrusive. To get the value of the textbox you simply use the `.value` property of the textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        if (btn.addEventListener) {
            btn.addEventListener("click", btnClick, false);
        } else if (btn.attachEvent) {
            btn.attachEvent("onclick", btnClick);
        }
    };
    function btnClick() {
        alert(document.getElementById("percent").value);
    }
</script>
```